# Freeing subordinates?

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
typedef struct A
{
    int* whatever;  
} A;


int main(void)
{
    A* foo = (A)malloc(sizeof(A));
    foo->whatever = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
    free(A); // leak? (foo->whatever)
    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to free each component of a struct / composite data type, or can I just free the struct?

Comment: Compile with all warning levels set to maximum. That should have told you assigning an int to a int* is invalid.

Comment: @ZanLynx: that looks like it might just be a typo...

Comment: You might like `talloc`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3065381/13422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that is malloc'd needs to be freed

Answer (score 1):

For each `malloc` in a program, there must be a `free`. That's the rule, plain and simple.

Since you `malloc` twice, `free` twice.

Comment: And do it in the correct order. Last memory malloced should be first memory freed.

Comment: @ZanLynx: That's less important. Objects can outlive other objects.

Comment: Not when they are nested. If the container object is free'd first then it is invalid to use its pointer to get at the pointer inside.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Yes, but that's not a _general_ rule about `malloc` and `free`. You could just as easily copy the contained object's pointer somewhere and use that to free it later.

Comment: It's important in this case...if you free the struct first, the pointer inside is no longer valid and can't be freed.