# Does malloc work recursively?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a vector of `struct a`, size not known at compile time.

Every `struct a` contains a pointer to a vector of a `struct b`. Length of vector of `struct b` is not known at compile time.

So if I do this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct b {
    int n;
 };

 struct a {
    int n;
    struct b *v;
 };

 int main() {

    struct a *s;
    struct a *ta;
    struct b *tb;

    s = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a) * 32);
    s->v = (struct b*)malloc(sizeof(struct b) * 32);
    s->n = 1234;
    ((s->v)+1)->n = 5678;

    fprintf(stderr, "%p: %i / %p: %i\n", s, s->n, (s->v)+1, ((s->v)+1)->n);

    ta = s;
    tb = (s->v)+1;

    free(s);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p: %i / %p: %i\n", ta, ta->n, tb, tb->n);

    return 0;
 }
```

Outputs for example:

```
 0x1cb3010: 1234 / 0x1cb3224: 5678
 0x1cb3010: -1526330504 / 0x1cb3224: 5678
```

Does the struct b vector by any chance automagically get freed when there are allocated memory blocks within the same pointer? Or do I have to first free the individual `struct b` vectors for every item in the `struct a` vector?

*[The question on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942676/recursively-freeing-c-structs) has been suggested as a duplicate of this post, but the question here asks about existing features within the `free` call, instead of asking for advice on how to make a recursive procedure.*

Comment: no, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Also you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: Which part of the documentation made you believe anything like that might be the case?

Comment: Don't be casting the result of `malloc`. For every `malloc` you must call `free` to avoid a memory leak. And yes, that applies to inner nested `struct`s as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942676/recursively-freeing-c-structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every `malloc()` you must have a symmetric `free()`.

if you are working in linux environment you can use valgrind to check your program.

run:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./my_prog
```

and read about your errors

Comment: I didn't know about this `valgrind`-tool. This is a good, constructive answer, which makes it easy for anyone else reading this to prove for themselves whether or not there is a leak. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, you must have a `free` for every `malloc`.

Better answer: Still no, but you can write a function to free multiple struct members. Here's an example:

```
void freeStruct(struct a *foo)
{
    free(foo->v);
    free(foo);
}
```

Also: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `free()` allows `free(NULL)`.  A free-like function would mimic that functionality closer if it protected itself, like with `if (foo) free(foo->v);`